# GDK retrieving account information

Tags: google-oauth, google-glass, google-gdk

I am a Google Glass application developer. During developing one application, I encountered some problems.

My application have landed on MyGlass and it's on review process, so it's not publicly visible. It only can be seen by me.

The problem is:

1. When I turn on my Glassware in MyGlass, my glass device never receive my application. Should I receive it or not? And why didn't I receive it?
2. I have launched the method `mirror.accounts.insert.execute()` from https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication, and it didn't raise an exception, but I didn't receive the account information and the `authToken` on my glass device. This is because I haven't received my application on my glass device, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed correct: the token will only be sync'ed and available once the APK from MyGlass has been downloaded to your device and installed. After this first installation, you can safely replace the APK with a development one using `adb install -r` as long as it's using the same certificate.

Make sure to check that your device is connected to the internet, especially through WIFI. If that doesn't work, ask the Glass review team to help you out and check if there are any internal issues that would prevent your APK from being downloaded.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.I can receive apk and accountType,accountName now.But only one problem is when i invoke mAccountManager.getUserData() in my application of version 2.0 which have not been submmited (the application i have submit is version 1.0),it raised an Exception:java.lang.SecurityException:caller uid 10086 is different than the authenticator's uid
.Dose mean that i can't test mAccountManager.getUserData() in an demo application or my application of version 2.0.  Another,my application of version 1.0 don't define authenticator.xml.

Comment: This can happen for two reasons: you are not using the same certificate between the app you've submitted and your dev app or you uninstalled the downloaded app before installing your dev app: for the latter, make sure you install using `adb install -r <PATH_TO_APK>`